# shortening my data labels

Tags: linux, unix

So, I have this line as an example. This is a label for my data:
d__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Betaproteobacteria|o__Burkholderiales|f__Alcaligenaceae|g__Advenella

All of the labels of my data are in this format. What I would like to do is just remove most of it, leaving the last part which is the g__Advenella. I'm quite noob and in a hurry, so it would save me a lot of time if you can help me. I have already extracted of the labels of my data and saved it in a text file.

Comment: a basic `sed -i.bak 's/^.*|\(g.*$\)/\1/' filename` would do it in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Perl, Sed, or Awk.

**Perl**

```
perl -pe 's/^.*\|([^\|]+)$/\1/' input-file > output-file
```

**SED**

```
sed -r 's/^.*\|([^\|]+)$/\1/' input-file > output-file
```

**AWK**

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="|"; } {print $NF}' input-file > output-file
```

**Pure Bash**

```
while read -r line; do
  echo ${line/*|/}
done < input-file > output-file
```

Comment: Wow. You're amazing. Thanks!